# How can I track the path of open the URL process in android studio?

Tags: android, android-source

I am trying to track the URL-Open process, to do some changes in the AOSP, so I used android studio to do that, by opening URLs from messages (in the emulator) and simply by opening links in Google and doing "attach debugger to android process", many processes have been shown so I try to debug many processes, but there is no output.

so am I on the right way to achieving my goal? and what is the solution to my problem?

the needed path: all the classes and functions used when a user clicks a URL.

before this solution, I try to download AOSP in Ubuntu but it didn't work because I used mac m1 which is an ARM architecture

Comment: "the needed path: all the classes and functions used when a user clicks a URL" -- there will be thousands of these, spread across multiple processes and code bases. And the details will vary depend on the app in which "user clicks a URL", as different apps can do different things when the user does something like that.

Comment: @CommonsWare what if I use the messages application to track the path, what is the right way to do that?

Comment: "what if I use the messages application" -- there are many apps that might be described as "messages application", and it is unlikely that I will have used whichever one you are thinking of. "what is the right way to do that?" -- that will still be thousands of classes and methods, spread across multiple processes and code bases. At minimum, it will include code in the "messages application", the Android SDK/framework, and 1+ core OS processes.